# c# Async task running with return value for a function with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

So I've searched the Net for ways of executing some heavy tasks async to keep the UI responsive. And to be quite honest - I did not find anything that describes my actual situation in a way *I can understand*.

So I have this code snippet:

```
List<myType> indexedItems = new List<myType>();           
Task t = new Task.Run(() => indexedItems = FileHandling.ReadIndexFile(downloadPath));
lblProgress.Content = "Reading index file...";
lstItems.ItemsSource = null;
t.Wait();
```

What I actually want is to run the `ReadIndexFile` function with the paramether `downloadPath` to write the value of `indexItems` while allowing me to repaint and alter the UI and then wait for the Task to finish.

I've ran into so many problems with that piece of code that I just ask for an example for this particular scenario and a brief explanation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT
Original snippet with plain old sync. execution to show what happens:

```
if (File.Exists(downloadPath + @"\index.sbmdi"))
        {
            lblProgress.Content = "Reading index file...";
            lstMangas.ItemsSource = null;
            indexedMangas = FileHandling.ReadIndexFile(downloadPath);
            categoryList = Library.BuildCategoryList(indexedMangas);

            lstMangas.ItemsSource = indexedMangas;
            lblProgress.Content = "Ready.";
        }
lblProgress.Content = "Ready.";
prgrssUpper.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

Then there are some UI updates in another method which are not related to this data, just updating labels, buttons, etc.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with `async`/`await` in C#. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: What kind of application? WinForms, WPF?

Comment: @jeroenh it's WPF

Comment: And what's running this code? What happens after you get the result in `indexedItems`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto there is some seconds worth of magic happening to it and then finally it gets displayed in a dataGrid. Please remember that I really want to understand this issue, not just get a plain solution...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show that, since it's a bit unfortunate that you left out updating the UI after the asynchronous work which is quite important for answering

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've added the original code snippet so you can check what gets done. Also: in the original there was no instanciation for the list - this is normally handled in the init of the window but when I tried this earlier it told me about the list belonging to the original thread so I tried to move the instanciation...

Comment: The `BuildCategoryList` is the worst part. It takes several seconds, sometime more. When this is happening, I definately need the user to know, that it's reading the index and building this list.

Comment: @Matthew I've read this article before. As I get it, I have to call 'natives' like `GetStringAsync` and such. Isn't it possible to just move this function to another thread, update the UI and then wait for the other thread to finish?

Comment: @traxx2012 Yep, and that's what my answer does (it still uses `FileHandling.ReadIndexFile`). The downside is that now you have to worry about multi-threading issues in `ReadIndexFile`, whereas if your only async calls are to known-good functions like `GetStringAsync`, you probably don't. That's why I said that adding `ReadIndexFileAsync` is the best (not only) way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to add an asynchronous method `async Task FileHandling.ReadIndexFileAsync(string path)`. If you can't make changes to `FileHandling`, try something like this:

```
async Task MySnippet(string downloadPath)
{
    // Start reading the index file, but don't wait for the result.
    Task<List<myType>> indexedItemsTask = Task.Run(() => FileHandling.ReadIndexFile(downloadPath));
    // Alternatively, if you can add a method FileHandling.ReadIndexFileAsync:
    // Task<List<myType>> indexedItemsTask = FileHandling.ReadIndexFileAsync(downloadPath);

    // Update the UI.
    lblProgress.Content = "Reading index file...";
    lstItems.ItemsSource = null;

    // *Now* wait for the result.
    List<myType> indexedItems = await indexedItemsTask;

    // Do stuff with indexedItems.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `Task.Run`, not `new Task.Run`. This will not compile.

Comment: I've tried to change `ReadIndexFile` to `public static async Task<List<Manga>> ReadIndexFileAsync (string path)` and now I get "FileHandling has no definition for ReadIndexFile". This is what I originally meant - I don't understand the errors happpening when I try to do async magic.

Comment: @traxx2012 Converting a synchronous method to `async` involves more than just changing the signature. You should probably take some time to read up on `async`/`await` before continuing.

Comment: The error you see is because you replaced `ReadIndexFile` with `ReadIndexFileAsync`, but you're still calling `ReadIndexFile`. Replace `Task.Run(() => FileHandling.ReadIndexFile(downloadPath))` with just `FileHandling.ReadIndexFileAsync(downloadPath)`. But if you don't change the implementation of `ReadIndexFileAsync` to use async IO, it will still run synchronously.

Comment: @Matthew I needed some time to actually understand your example but I think I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: @traxx2012 Awesome :) Good luck!